# Vue-GTM Error : You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-tag-manager

I am using [@gtm-support/vue2-gtm"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@gtm-support/vue2-gtm): "^1.0.0" in one of my Vue-2 applications and the Vue versions are as follows:

```
"vue": "^2.5.2",
"vue-cookies": "^1.5.4",
"vue-i18n": "^8.0.0",
"vue-recaptcha": "^1.1.1",
"vue-router": "^3.0.1",
"vue-scrollto": "^2.17.1",
"vue-session": "^1.0.0",
"vuex": "^3.0.1"
```

and for the Webpack and Vue-Loader :

```
 "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
  "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
  "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
  "dotenv-webpack": "^4.0.0",
  "vue-loader": "^13.3.0",
  "webpack": "^3.6.0",
  "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1",
  "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.22.3",
  "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
```

Now, when I start my application, I get the following error:

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors                                                                                                                                                                                                                                3:45:02 PM

 error  in ./node_modules/@gtm-support/core/lib/utils.js

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (30:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|     const queryString = new URLSearchParams({
|         id,
|         ...((_c = config.queryParams) !== null && _c !== void 0 ? _c : {})
|     });
|     script.src = `https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?${queryString}`;

 @ ./node_modules/@gtm-support/core/lib/index.js 9:14-32
 @ ./node_modules/@gtm-support/vue2-gtm/dist/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8002 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js

 error  in ./node_modules/@gtm-support/core/lib/gtm-support.js

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (44:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|             defer: false,
|             compatibility: false,
|             ...options
|         };
|         // @ts-expect-error: Just remove the id from options

 @ ./node_modules/@gtm-support/core/lib/index.js 7:20-44
 @ ./node_modules/@gtm-support/vue2-gtm/dist/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8002 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js
```

In the `main.js` file. I have the following code:

```
import VueGtm from '@gtm-support/vue2-gtm'

Vue.use(VueGtm, {
  id: 'GTM-IDXX',
  defer: false,
  enabled: true,
  debug: true,
  loadScript: true
})
```

And I have a `util.js` file, and there I have the function for tracking events:

```
export default submitGTMEvents = (category, action, label) => {
  if (label === undefined || label === '') label = window.location.href
  const value = Number(store.getters.transactionId)
  Vue.gtm.push({
    event: null,
    category: category,
    action: action,
    label: label,
    value: value
  })
}
```

I call this function from my components. I am using the `1.0.0` version here as other versions also show me the same error, and thought an earlier version would sometimes fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I have been facing the same issue with `@gtm-support/vue-gtm`.

Setting up `vue.config.js` worked for me:

```js
module.exports = { transpileDependencies: [ '@gtm-support/core' ] };
```

Related: [IE 11 support](https://github.com/gtm-support/core#ie-11-support)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, using **v1.3.0** of the @gtm-support/vue2-gtm package solved it for me.

Comment: Same issue with version 2.0.0 had to downgrade to version 1.3.0